# Using a nested name specifier in CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I'm using CRPT and need to access a parameter in the base class which is defined in the derived class. It works when used in a member function, but not in a (I'm guessing) compile time expression (the problem occurs when defining a type). The following code illustrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename impl_t>
struct base {
// no complaints
  void print () {
    std::cout << "Base, impl_t::i_q = " << impl_t::i_q << std::endl;
  }
// compiler error:
//                 clang++: no member named 'i_q' in 'deriv_t'
//                 g++:     incomplete type ‘deriv_t’ used in nested name specifier
  using vec_t = std::array<double, impl_t::i_q>;
};

struct deriv_t : public base<deriv_t> {
  static const std::size_t i_q = 1;
};

int main () {
  deriv_t d;
  d.print();
}
```

I'm just wondering what rules are broken here? The solution I've come up with is to define `i_q` alongside `impl_t` in the template, but would like to know if there is a more tidy way to solve the problem.

Solution:

Thanks to Evg here is the solution:

```
template <typename impl_t>
struct traits;

template <typename impl_t>
struct base_t {
  void print () {
    std::cout << "Base, impl_t::i_q = " << traits<impl_t>::i_q << std::endl;
  }
  using vec_t = std::array<double, traits<impl_t>::i_q>;
};

struct deriv_t;

template <>
struct traits<deriv_t> {
  static const std::size_t i_q = 1;
};
struct deriv_t : public base_t<deriv_t> {
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`impl_t` is an incomplete type in `base`. You can solve the problem either using another template parameter or using a type traits technique:

```
template<class>
struct traits;

template<>
struct traits<deriv_t>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t i_q = 1;
};

...

void print () {
    std::cout << "Base, i_q = " << traits<impl_t>::i_q << std::endl;
}

using vec_t = std::array<double, traits<impl_t>::i_q>;
```

You don't have complaints in `print()` because at the point of its instantiation `impl_t` becomes a complete type.

Comment: Thanks for your response, any suggestion as to where to start research for type traits technique? I've opened the cppreference page on the `type_traits` library and am slightly intimidated.

Comment: 1) Alexandrescu A. Modern C++ Design. Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied. 2) Vandevoorde D. C++ Templates. The Complete Guide.

Comment: @FChambers, `<type_traits>` library itself is not what you need here. It contains ready-to-use traits, but you need to write your own.

Comment: Thanks for the example code, it can be used to solve the problem. I have amended the question with the solution. Thanks again!